# ExtJS 4.1 : How to adjust column width to content in a grid?

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a column to display db ids and I would like this column to adjust its width automatically to the longest one. I have found a config option called [`shrinkWrap`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-shrinkWrap) but I don't see any result on the screen.

Comment: I am not sure but did you try using `autoWidth: true` setting to columns?

Comment: I'm sorry but `autoWidth` seems not to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a private function `expandToFit` which can be used on the container object of the grid header.

Try something like this on the `Ext.grid.column.Column` object after all the records are loaded in the grid, for instance on the event `viewReady` of the `Ext.grid.Panel`:

```
column.ownerCt.expandToFit(column);
```

Iterate through the columns and call the above statement per column you want to have expanded.

Answer (score -4):

Try using the flex property like so:

```
{
   text:"Ids",
   dataIndex:'Ids',
   flex:1
}
```

Comment: The width calculated with `flex` is relative to the other columns. I have found a config option called [`shrinkWrap`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-shrinkWrap) but I don't see any result on the screen.